# find attributes names of child with specific value

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to get from this XML file, with XPath, all the attributes names that have a child with value 'General'. I couldn't find how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Systems>
  <system name="SystemName">
    <systemType>Generic</systemType>
    <servers>
      <server order="1">
        <serverName>Server1Name</serverName>
        <dataSensetivity>1</dataSensetivity>
      </server>
    </servers>
  </system>
  <system name="NewSystemName">
    <systemType>AD</systemType>
    <servers>
      <server order="1">
        <serverName>system1</serverName>
        <dataSensetivity>1</dataSensetivity>
      </server>
      <server order="1">
        <serverName>system2</serverName>
        <dataSensetivity>0</dataSensetivity>
      </server>
    </servers>
  </system>
</Systems>
```

Comment: *I couldn't find how to do that*... Show how you tried *to do that*. Also clarify what do you mean by *"all the attributes names that have a child"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XPath will find all the name attributes that are attached to elements that have a child element who's value is equal to 'General'.

```
//*[* = 'General']/@name
```

You could also be more specific and compare the value of the `text()` nodes of those child elements:

```
//*[*/text() = 'General']/@name
```

Your example XML doesn't have any elements with the value "General", did you mean "Generic"?

Comment: Yes i meant Generic. Thank you! your answer did the job :)